# TSQL multi-part identifier could not be bound (explicit join for select x table in inner join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running into a problem because I am trying to do an explicit join in an inner join where I am trying to select certain values from another table.

My SQL:

```
SELECT A.OrderID
     , A.ItemID
     , A.Line
     , B.LID
     , B.Quantity 
FROM Sales A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT X.OrderID
                 , X.Line
                 , SUM(X.Quantity) AS Quantity
                 , X.DestinationID
                 , X.SerialNum 
            FROM SalesDetail X 
            WHERE X.OrderID = A.OrderID 
            GROUP BY X.OrderID, X.Line, X.DestinationID, X.SerialNum
           ) AS C
            ON A.Line = C.Line 
           AND B.Quantity = C.Quantity 
           AND B.SerialNum = C.SerialNum
INNER JOIN SalesContents B 
            ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID 
           AND A.ItemID = B.ItemID
WHERE A.OrderID = '12345'
AND  A.ItemID = 'ABC123';
```

Now I can remove the WHERE clause within the X table and filter it within the inner join but I would like to filter it right when I am querying the values. Is there a way to rewrite this statement so that the unbound identifier can be worked around?

Comment: just move the conditions `AND B.Quantity = C.Quantity
  AND B.SerialNum = C.SerialNum` after you `join` SalesContents  B (alias).

Comment: Your query just makes no sense.  The join conditions refer to table aliases before they are defined.  I find it helpful to use table abbreviations for the table aliases (such as `s` for `sales` rather than `a`).  If you fix the query to order the conditions correctly and remove the `where` clause in the subquery, your might be able to fix the query yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your subquery's WHERE clause to the join's ON clause. Alias 'A' is not defined in your subquery.

```
SELECT A.OrderID
     , A.ItemID
     , A.Line
     , B.LID
     , B.Quantity 
FROM Sales A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT X.OrderID
                 , X.Line
                 , SUM(X.Quantity) AS Quantity
                 , X.DestinationID
                 , X.SerialNum 
            FROM SalesDetail X 
            --WHERE X.OrderID = A.OrderID 
            GROUP BY X.OrderID, X.Line, X.DestinationID, X.SerialNum
           ) AS C
            ON A.Line = C.Line 
           AND C.OrderID = A.OrderID --<-- move the filter here
           AND B.Quantity = C.Quantity 
           AND B.SerialNum = C.SerialNum
INNER JOIN SalesContents B 
            ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID 
           AND A.ItemID = B.ItemID
WHERE A.OrderID = '12345'
-- you could also put it here instead
AND  A.ItemID = 'ABC123';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer an alias in your joins which hasn't been defined.

If you take the subquery in the end only then you can join it to Alias `C`, Something like ....

```
SELECT A.OrderID
     , A.ItemID
     , A.Line
     , B.LID
     , B.Quantity 
FROM Sales A 
INNER JOIN SalesContents B 
            ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID 
           AND A.ItemID = B.ItemID
INNER JOIN (SELECT X.OrderID
                 , X.Line
                 , SUM(X.Quantity) AS Quantity
                 , X.DestinationID
                 , X.SerialNum 
            FROM SalesDetail X 
            WHERE X.OrderID = A.OrderID 
            GROUP BY X.OrderID, X.Line, X.DestinationID, X.SerialNum
           ) AS C
            ON A.Line = C.Line 
           AND B.Quantity = C.Quantity 
           AND B.SerialNum = C.SerialNum
WHERE A.OrderID = '12345'
AND  A.ItemID = 'ABC123';
```

Comment: You are still referencing A in the subquery